# Blocked Worker Threads in WCF

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, threadpool

In Juval Lowy's text "Programming WCF Services", he writes:

> ...when the client invokes a method of the form Begin() with AsyncPattern set to true, this tells WCF not to try to directly invoke a method with that name on the service. Instead, WCF should use a thread from the thread pool to synchronously call the underlying method.  The synchronous call will block the thread from the thread pool, not the calling client (p441).
>
> When each asynchronous method's execution is complete, instead of quietly returning to the pool, the worker thread calls the completion callback (p447).

What I'm hearing is that a (worker?) thread is being blocked while the calling thread continues.  This means that if I make thousands of such (long-running) async calls from the client, I will start killing my thread pool performance because the threadpool will start spawning new threads to replace all the ones that are sitting around blocked.

But perhaps that story has changed since Juval wrote the book?  I notice someone who [contradicts what Juval says](http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/net-worker-threads-io-threads-and-asynchronous-programming/), but in a piece written fully a year earlier.

What is the *real* truth here?